# How to disable parent page of modal in angular

Tags: css, angular

I have a modal window in Angular 4 that works fine but if the user clicks on the background / parent page the modal is closed.

I have found some solutions that suggest using backdrop='static' and keyboard=false when opening the modal but our modal uses a local Dialog class with a BehaviorSubject object so is opened using the .next method. I've also tried setting these attributes using div config but to no avail.

Therefore I'm looking for another solution, maybe using CSS or another setting / attribute that can be directly applied to the parent page or modal HTML.

See below for some of the relevant code.

dialog.component.ts:

```
constructor(private location: PlatformLocation,
    private _dialog: DialogService,
    private router: Router) { }

open() {
    this.showDialog = true;
    const body = document.body;
    body.classList.add('cell-modal-open');
}

close() {
    this.dialog = undefined;
}

private handleDialog(d: Dialog) {
    if (!d) {
        this.close();
    } else if (d.template) {
        if (this.showDialog) {
            this.close();
        }
        this.dialog = d;
        this.open();
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this
        ._dialog
        .getDialog()
        .subscribe({
            next: (d) => { this.handleDialog(d); console.log('subscribed dialog') },
            error: (err) => this.handleDialogError(err)
        });
    this.initialiseRoutingEventListeners();
}
```

dialog.service.ts

```
private d: Dialog = { template: null, size: DialogSizeEnum.XLarge };
private dialogSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Dialog>({ template: null, size: DialogSizeEnum.XLarge });

constructor() { }

showDialog(template: TemplateRef<any>, size = DialogSizeEnum.XLarge, requiresAction = false) {
    Object.assign(this.d, { template: template, size: size, requiresAction: requiresAction });
    if (this.d !== null) {
        this.dialogSubject.next(this.d);
    }
}

getDialog(): BehaviorSubject<Dialog> {
    return this.dialogSubject;
}

clear() {
    this.dialogSubject.next(null);
}
```

**Any suggested approaches are welcome!**

Comment: *but our modal uses a local Dialog class with a BehaviorSubject object so is opened using the .next method.* I see no dependency here. How about shoing actual HTML and related CSS ?

Comment: I agree with @Antoniossss, What you want to accomplish is mostly related to the css/html side of things. With that said I'd recommend reading up on the [best practices of modals](https://uxplanet.org/best-practices-for-modals-overlays-dialog-windows-c00c66cddd8c). As well as [some css tips](https://css-tricks.com/considerations-styling-modal/) you can use to implement one.

Comment: I found a workaround anyway by adding flag to the close() method and adding condition to only set to undefined if true (i.e. from a valid location). Thanks to you both for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Added flag to the close() method and adding condition to only set to undefined if true (i.e. from a valid location).